# Classes and Bitmaps

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+, handle

I have a very interesting predicament at the moment. I have a custom object called `misc.Weapon`that contains a bitmap. Example:

```
private Image _proj;
public Image ProjectileImage
{
    get
    {
        return _proj;
    }
    set
    {
        _proj = value;
    }
}
```

Unless I'm wrong, the image class takes up a handle. I've been having some problems with too many handles. I also have a massive library of `misc.Weapon`s
called `weapons`. This is what it looks like:

```
public class Weapons
{
    public misc.Trinket endanklet = new misc.Trinket("Anklet of Edurance", "Given to the 4th hero of Aebenclaw during the war, to live for a 100 years more.");
    public void inittrink()
    {
        endanklet.Method = () =>{PSTATS.maxhealth += 50;};
        endanklet.end = () =>{PSTATS.maxhealth -= 50;};
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Speeds:
    /// 1 = very slow
    /// 2 = slow
    /// 3 = normal
    /// 4 = quick
    /// 5 = lightning
    /// </summary>
    public misc.Weapon natureblade = new misc.Weapon("Blade of Nature", "Laiden with the flowers of The 9 Wreathes", 22, 22, "M", 3, Properties.Resources.BladeOfNature);
    public misc.Weapon dagger = new misc.Weapon("Dagger", "Sharp as the eye that throws it", 4, 0, "M", 5, Properties.Resources.Dagger);
    public misc.Weapon bluescepter = new misc.Weapon("Saphire Sceptre", "This is what happens when a saphire is put on a stick", 7, 15, "S", 2, Properties.Resources.SaphireSceptre);
    public misc.Weapon silscepter = new misc.Weapon("Platinum Sceptre", "Dat platinum doe", 15, 40, "S", 2, Properties.Resources.SilverSceptre);
    public misc.Armour rustychainmail = new misc.Armour(7, "Rusty Chainmail", "So out of fashion");

    public misc.Armour wraitharmour = new misc.Armour(8, "Shadow plated hide", "Found in a warehouse in the southern spike, which was said to be haunted");
    public misc.Armour telepathic = new misc.Armour(2, "Telepathic armour", "Use your mind!");

    public misc.Weapon volcanictome = new misc.Weapon("Volcanic Storm", "Fire is always a slow death, the Volcanic Storm, slightly less so", 5, 40, 6, 3, Properties.Resources.VolcanicTome,Properties.Resources.VSProjectile);
    public misc.Weapon icyblow = new misc.Weapon("Icy Blow", "Make's your head hurt", 18, 10, "M", 1, Properties.Resources.IcyBlow);
}
```

I need this library going, but for each weapon, there is a few valuable handles being taken away from my PC's memory. I need to be able to reference each weapon individually (because I have them to drop randomly and I dont want to make a new `misc.Weapon` on the spot) without the cost of GDI+ objects/ handles.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `ProjectileImage` property lazy. Instead of loading and assigning the `Bitmap` right away, you could only assign it the first time the property is accessed.

Also, there are *many* handles available. The fact that you're running out of handles makes me suspicious. Are you properly disposing of resources? Are you sure that you remove all references eventually so they can be GC'ed?

Comment: How exactly should I implement this method?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was actually a few lines of code to do with other classes making the class the that called them :/